# How to convert xml file to C# object?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to convert this xml file to C# object but it doesn't work. I can't to get text between Group tags. The classes structure let me to get childs inside Group tag, but when Group tag has just one text inside, I can't select it.

I give the XML structure and my classes.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Main>
  <Group>
      <NV>BasicPars</NV>
      <Property>
          <NV>Name</NV>
          <Value>wzorzec</Value>
      </Property>
      <Property>
          <NV>UseFixedSizes</NV>
          <Value>False</Value>
      </Property>
  </Group>
  <Group>EventPars</Group>
  <Group>Registers</Group>
</Main>
```

My classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Property")]
public class Property { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="NV")] 
    public string NV { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Value")] 
    public string Value { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Group")]
public class Group { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="NV")] 
    public string NV { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Property")] 
    public List<Property> Property { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Main")]
public class Main { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Group")] 
    public List<Group> Group { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to process this XML?

Comment: The XML you have shared is not valid. An XML document must have a single root tag, but yours has three `Groups` at the root level. Try pasting it into any XML validator

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: The XML currently in your question is invalid

Comment: Please tell me why. I corrected that.

Comment: You fixed your question 6 mins ago, and my comment was 8 mins ago. This latest revision when I made my comment was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76777271/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Serializer
    {       
        public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
            {
                return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
            }
        }

        public string Serialize<T>(T ObjectToSerialize)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(ObjectToSerialize.GetType());

            using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, ObjectToSerialize);
                return textWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @mike1234 This doesn't answer your question. Why have you marked it as the answer?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 3):

First, you only need `XmlRoot` on the root object (that is, `Main`). Remove it from the others.

In order to capture the text inside an element, [use `[XmlText]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization).

The fixed classes are:

```
public class Property { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="NV")] 
    public string NV { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Value")] 
    public string Value { get; set; } 
}

public class Group { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="NV")] 
    public string NV { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Property")] 
    public List<Property> Property { get; set; }
    
    [XmlText]
    public string InnerText { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="Main")]
public class Main { 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="Group")] 
    public List<Group> Group { get; set; } 
}
```

Which [deserializes correctly](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RrBTfC).